# Magento SOAP API - getting product attachments

Tags: magento, soap, product, attachment

I am using SOAP API for Magento to get every data about products made in Magento. So far, everything went juuust fine, you get get everything using API commands which are in Magento documentation.

However, I am stuck with attachments. There is a attribute in Magento called "Attachments" for each product and it contains links to pdf files. I tried every API and trick including exports and filters and I can't get that data. Unfortunately, I can work only with API and SOAP v1.

I tried "product_downloadable_link.list" of course, but I get an error: "Caught exception: Incorrect product type. Downloadable content, can be added only to "downloadable" products."

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1 or Magento 2? 
Also if will be helpful if you provide the API endpoint that you are using, and if this is a Magento 2, the custom attributes are retrievable via extension attributes.

Comment: I think it's Magento 1, I just asked someone and they said it's basically not possible using SOAP API.